# Retrieve Team Foundation Server Backup which is not checked in

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

First, I am new to Team Foundation Server Management system. So here is the story:
We have one solution which has 19 projects in it. The last time the projects were checked in was on 9/12/2016 and have not been checked in since then. Many program changes were made since then and on 5/01/2017 while working on the projects in that solution, I suddenly received a message saying, 'The source code have been changed. DO you want to retrieve the changes?' Options provided:

- No
- No To All
- Yes
- Yes To All

Since I am the only developer who was working on those projects and I knew no one else worked on it since past few days, so I selected 'No To All' option and carried on making changes. Later when I tried to build the projects, it popped up several errors and did not rebuild/build projects. After examining the code, the finding was the code part of the projects seems to be up to date (till that moment) but the Form part and the form designers of the projects seemed to be way old and have been mismatched with the code.cs part of the form. 
First thing I did was to Get Latest Version (Recursive) but somehow the Visual Studio kept the latest program changes in the code part and pulled the old version of many other projects in the solution. 
Is it possible to retrieve latest changes (day before 5/01/2017) of code from my local workspace even if I have not checked in on that day? Any help will be useful. 
Thank you in advance.

P.S. I did many changes to the program in the project over 3/01/2017 and 04/01/2017 and have built and rebuilt the projects, all with success.

Comment: I know..oh boy!

Comment: If local changes have been overwritten, there is no way to recover them with TFS. When you do a Get Latest, Visual Studio will try and merge changes on any file you have checked out. Are you sure you lost data?

Comment: I lost a months work, equal to thousands of lines of code! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible. TFS relies on you to push changes to it, so if you haven't then all you have left is what is on your local workspace. If you have overwritten your local workspace then changes you made in the last couple of days are gooooooooooone....

This is a lesson for you (we've all done it :). Look to use shelvesets regularly for the work that isn't ready for checking in but you want a copy of it kept.

Comment: Additionally I would recommend creating a separate Branch if you need to work independantly on a project meant to last for some time (weeks, months). This way you can check in your changes without interfering with others and you keep track of the history of your changes